# using jquery in rails3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have some questions on jquery in rails3. If I put a function like this in my `application.js`. Is it appropriate to put my JS in there rather than in my views?

```
$(function())
{
$("alert").onclick(function());
....
});
```

How do I call it within a view? Doesnt the function need an identifier or name? Is `link_to_function` a good way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper way of doing it:

```
$(function()
{
  $(".alert").click(function( .... ));
  ....
});
```

Don't put this in your views. Just add to to application.js

This attaches a click handler to your links with the class `alert`. Function will be called automatically when the click event fires (when you click the link).

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Add a CSS class with the same name to the link that you want jQuery to attach your event handler to. For single items you could also us and ID.